# Required disk space on rasperry pi with opencv

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a 8gb sd card and when i install the raspian on it the file manager inside raspian shows the disk space about 700 mb. Is that normal cuz the raspian requires about 3.5gb. Please help me . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so most likely you haven't resized your SD-Card, maybe look into [this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition). Make sure you do an backup, as he tells you on the answer. Was a 1 min google lookup. Maybe try to search by your self the next time.

Edit: I also found out there is a even easier way given by raspberry, just enter `sudo rasps-config` and  use `expand_rootfs`

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is [Resize Flash Partitions](http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions)

The article may be long to read but it's very useful because you can apply it for many Linux based operating systems.